# Pytorch Repeating loss and AUC- When using cumulative loss

Tags: pytorch, loss

I am using PyTorch to accumulate and add losses, and then implement backpropagation(loss.backward()) at the end.

At this time, the loss is not updated and remains almost the same, and the AUC repeats exactly the same. Are there any points I haven't considered when using cumulative losses?

Thank you so much for any reply. :)

Below is the loss calculation that occurs in one batch.

```
            opt.zero_grad()
            for s in range(len(qshft)): 
              for a in range(len(qshft[0])):
                if(m[s][a]):
                  y_pred = (y[s][a] * one_hot(qshft[s].long(), self.num_q)).sum(-1)
                  y_pred = torch.masked_select(y_pred, m[s])
                  t = torch.masked_select(rshft[s], m[s])
                  loss += binary_cross_entropy(y_pred, t).clone().detach().requires_grad_(True)
                  count += 1
            
            loss = torch.tensor(loss/count,requires_grad=True)


            loss.backward()
            opt.step()

            loss_mean.append(loss.detach().cpu().numpy())
```

Comment: Too many manipulations with variable `loss` in cycle, why not just `loss += binary_cross_entropy(y_pred, t)`? And after cycle just dividing by count also should be enough, like `loss /= count`

Answer (score 0):

Your following operation of `detach` removes the computation graph, so the `loss.backward()` and `opt.step()` won't update your weights which results in repeating loss and AUC.

```
loss += binary_cross_entropy(y_pred, t).clone().detach().requires_grad_(True)
```

You can do

```
loss += binary_cross_entropy(y_pred, t)
```

and change

```
loss = torch.tensor(loss/count,requires_grad=True)
```

to

```
loss = loss/count
```

But make sure you reset `count` and `loss` to 0 every time you go into this part.